# How to pass java object from the servlet to the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How to pass java object from the servlet to the jsp page.
I want to print strings from passed java object onto the jsp page.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: request.setAttribute(....);

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have to tried to search for this or at least read any book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set it in `HttpServletRequest`

```
getAttribute(java.lang.String name) 
setAttribute(java.lang.String name, java.lang.Object o)
```

To set it in `HttpSession`

```
setAttribute(String name, Object value) 
getAttribute(String name)
```

Suppose you set in request Object:

```
request.setAttribute("user", user);
```

where `user` class is as follows:

```
Class User{
     String name;
     int roll;
}
```

Following is the code in JSP in Expression Language (EL)

```
  ${user.name}
```

Here it will search for `user`  in `page`, `request`, `session`, `application context`.

hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is Possible to do that and ya what you can do is just put the Object in HttpSession or just Map Object into the Model and you can access it to the JSP Page.

For an Example

```
setAttribute(String name, Object value); 
getAttribute(String name);
```

and you can Access it to the JSP Using JSTL or whatever other you want to use. you can easily access it

and and Simple way is

```
${loopvariable.name}
```

and that way it will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `session.setAttribute()` and `session.getAttribute()`

In servlet do this way

```
HttpSession session=request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("hi","hi");
```

And in jsp you get it by using

```
session.getAttribute("hi");
```

You will get `hi`